# LINQ: Finding maximal element (not maximal value)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Assume you have a list of edges with given length (as double). Now you want to find the edge with maximal length. Is there an easy way to do this in LINQ?

Of course, I can first compute the maximal value with Max and then do comparison, but firstly, this would be a two computations and secondly comparing doubles for equality is a bad thing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data structure an what you're after? Either way there will be comparison happening from my understanding of your issue (whether you do it or a LINQ query does).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Jon Skeet has `MaxBy` in his MoreLINQ library: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq
- Also, look at [Observable.MaxBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.maxby%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
- Alternatively look at

  ```
  e.OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeProperty).First();
  ```

Comment: @Dmitry: Why is the `OrderBy` approach not a good advice? It's simple, it's already on board and (in most cases) it's fast enough.

Comment: @Dmitry Yet it is only way to create such construct in relational DB.

Comment: @Tim +1  Orderby is a valid answer [even if the default implementation is inefficient].  By placing it at the end sehe gives correct emphasis.

Comment: Really fast and competent answer.

Answer (score 0):

sehe beat me to the correct answer, so I'll use this to note a possibly flawed assumption:

> ...secondly comparing doubles for equality is a bad thing.

IIRC there *shouldn't* be any problem comparing a copied double for equality.  After all it's just 8 bytes.  The problem occurs in computation - or using two similar values from different sources.

That said, it's good to be scared of comparing floating point numbers :P